# Firebase dynamic linking - Continueuseractivity not returning dynamic link url

Tags: objective-c, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

My requirement is to handle universal links on the iOS application. But the dynamic link.url seems to be returning an error as below -

```
"@"error" : @"unauthorized user: username=social-app-invite methodName=/FirebaseLookupService.LookupAppsSummary protocol=loas securityLevel=integritY"
```

When i click on a dynamic link (https://****.app.goo.gl/****) from the notes app, my ios app will be directed to the following callback ->
In this function i have the following code -

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void(^)(NSArray * __nullable restorableObjects))restorationHandler
{
NSURL *incomingURL = userActivity.webpageURL;
if(incomingURL){
    BOOL handled = [[FIRDynamicLinks dynamicLinks]
                    handleUniversalLink:incomingURL
                    completion:^(FIRDynamicLink * _Nullable dynamicLink,
                                 NSError * _Nullable error) {
                        if (dynamicLink.url){`
                           **HANDLE THE DYNAMIC LINK HERE**
                        }else{
                           **CODE IS RETURNING ERROR** NSLog(@"error %@",error);
                        }
                    }];
    return handled;
}else{
    return false;
}

}
```

I have followed the firebase documentation correctly. Please suggest what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

I also met this issue. `handleUniversalLink()` returned always false. In my case my link parameter contained not just a URL but also parameters. So the final dynamic link got two question marks in it.

`https://app-id.app.goo.gl/?link=https://www.domain.com/resource?someParam=someValue&ibi=com.domain.appname`

If I escape the inner URL (link parameter) with percent escapes, it works fine.

`https://app-id.app.goo.gl/?link=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2Fresource%3FsomeParam%3DsomeValue&ibi=com.domain.appname`

Comment: I am trying to get an dynamic link , but handleuniversallink() always returns false and also not entered into the closure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void(^)(NSArray * __nullable restorableObjects))restorationHandler
{
    NSURL *url = userActivity.webpageURL;


    FIRDynamicLinks *links = [FIRDynamicLinks dynamicLinks];
    if([links matchesShortLinkFormat:url])
    {
        [links resolveShortLink:url completion:^(NSURL * _Nullable url, NSError * _Nullable error)
        {
                NSString *message =
                [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Deep link  \n:%@",
                 url];

                [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Deep-link Data"
                                            message:message
                                           delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil] show];



        }];

        return YES;
    }
 return false;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, am getting  myappid://google/link/  not the long dynamic link, any reason why its not returning dynamic link url. Thanks

Comment: You can get long dynamic link in block url, what i formated in "message" string.

Comment: I can get my long dynamic link in block section.

Comment: Try to put same code as my answer without any change.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Aklesh. But I am getting null for "url". Instead get an error for NSError.

Comment: Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=403 "(unauthorized user: username=social-app-invite methodName=/FirebaseLookupService.LookupAppsSummary protocol=loas securityLevel=integrity)" UserInfo={error=unauthorized user: username=social-app-invite methodName=/FirebaseLookupService.LookupAppsSummary protocol=loas securityLevel=integrity, GTLStructuredError=GSDK_GTLErrorObject 0x1642e6f0: {code:403 status?:"PERMISSION_DENIED" message:"unauthorized user: username=social-app-invite methodName=/FirebaseLookupService.LookupAppsSummary protocol=loas securityLevel=integrity" errors?:[1]}

Comment: @KavithaPai I tried to search your error and came to the point that there is something wrong with your configuration on firebase console. Are you using same credential as on firebase console?

Comment: @AkleshRathaur, The googleservice-info.plist you mean?

Comment: Where do i need to use the same credential?

Comment: @KavithaPai Can you send me your long and sort dynamic link?

Comment: @AkleshRathaur: Long dynamic link is this -> https://brej5.app.goo.gl/?link=http://erosnow.com/tv&isi=551666302&ibi=com.erosnow.erosnow&ius=erosnowapp://tv
and short one is this -> https://brej5.app.goo.gl/M4Bi

Comment: @KavithaPai check your identifier, team id, url scheme in xcode and also in firebase console. there should be some mismatch.

Comment: @AkleshRathaur: I have not added anything manually except the URI Scheme. I have downloaded the googleservice-info.plist from the firebase site and all other configurations are part of it.

Comment: @KavithaPai I will suggest you to watch a video on youtube for firebase invite and deep link.You will definitely get your solution.

Comment: okay i will do that.. But firebase invite is not required in my case. Just wondering why I am getting an error on that.

Comment: @AkleshRathaur: I think i found something. When i try to hit my dynamic link url from here - https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/firebasedynamiclinks/v1/. I get the following response -

Comment: "code": 403,
  "message": "Firebase Dynamic Links API has not been used in project google.com:apisexplorerconsole before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/overview?project=google.com:apisexplorerconsole then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
  "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",

Comment: @KavithaPai have you enabled now?

Comment: @AkleshRathaur: Yes, I have enabled dynamic linking api. Looks like it will take some number of hours to activate. Currently it is giving the same error.

Comment: @KavithaPai Ok. Try later.

Comment: Where did you create that project? on google console or firebase console

Comment: I had created the project on firebase console itself. Just had to add the firbase dynamic linking api from the link here - https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/overview?project=<project-name>

Comment: Ok. now you will get your solution.

Comment: I will check after few hours and post in this forum if it works.

Comment: That would be helpful to others.

Comment: @AkleshRathaur: Check my answer above. I was able to get the url successfully. But now my problem is i need the uri scheme value to navigate to the respective page. Something like "myapp://some link". Currently i get the deep link url only.  It navigates to the home page always. Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the dynamic link url value. There was an additional check in my code as below  -

`if (launchOptions != nil) 
 {`
`[FIROptions defaultOptions].deepLinkURLScheme = URL_SCHEME;`

`}`

Because of this check, the URL scheme was never getting initialised and hence was erroring out.

The code that i have posted above should return the right dynamic link url.

Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the message. But this one is already available in firebase deeplink demo and i integrated that. May be you not that's why you were facing an error.