# Upon clicking Firebase dynamic link - DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink returns false

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I am using Firebase dynamic links and I have few links that I have created in the firebase console.

Here is example short link that I copy pasted to an email and clicking:
https://app.xxx.com/deeplink/xyz

When we click on the link provided, the following function gets called:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool { }
```

I have tried capturing the dynamic link with following code and it always returns false and completion block was never executed:

```
let handled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(userActivity.webpageURL!) { dynamiclink, error in
   print("dyn:: ------- \(dynamiclink?.url)")
}
```

I have tried referring to similar issues here, here are few links:
1. https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/380
2. [Firebase dynamic linking - Continueuseractivity not returning dynamic link url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39657454/firebase-dynamic-linking-continueuseractivity-not-returning-dynamic-link-url)

But none of them worked. And this is the error I could see in the logs:
**Deep Link Web URL query is empty**

PS: I am using Firebase Dynamic Links version - 4.0.1

Comment: Hi! Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: @jhk, Yes. I forgot to setup FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains in Info.plist. Once that has been set, it started working

Comment: @jhk, Yes, that is what I missed too. Thanks. Adding it did the magic

Answer (score 7):

I forgot to setup FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains in Info.plist. Once that has been set, it started working