# iOS Firebase Dynamic Link with weird long dynamic link url format issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I encounter a weird issue with long dynamic link base on FirebaseDynamicLinks (4.0.8):

Have tried refer to similar issues [firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/380#issuecomment-343255857](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/380#issuecomment-343255857) and [DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57464004/upon-clicking-firebase-dynamic-link-dynamiclinks-dynamiclinks-handleuniversa)

My long dynamic link format is alike that :

https://example.page.link/?link=https://app.tdservice/account?to=create&apn=com.testDynamicAndroid.service.app&isi=1234567890&ibi=com.TestDynamiciOS.service

And already confirm my real link is normal by [appsearch-validation-tool](https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool/)

However, my implement of handleUniversalLink in AppDelegate without call back, cause the handled return NO....

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
continueUserActivity:(nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity
restorationHandler:
#if defined(__IPHONE_12_0) && (__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_12_0)
(nonnull void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler {
#else
(nonnull void (^)(NSArray *_Nullable))restorationHandler {
#endif  // __IPHONE_12_0
    if ([userActivity webpageURL] != nil) {
        NSString *incomingURL = [userActivity webpageURL].absoluteString;
        NSLog(@"Incoming URL is %@", incomingURL);

        BOOL handled = [[FIRDynamicLinks dynamicLinks] handleUniversalLink:userActivity.webpageURL
        completion:^(FIRDynamicLink * _Nullable dynamicLink,
        NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if (error != nil) {
                return NSLog(@"Found an error! %@", error.localizedDescription);
            }

            if (dynamicLink != nil && dynamicLink.url != nil) {
                [self handleIncomingDynamicLink:dynamicLink]; // additional declare
            } else {
                NSLog(@"This's weird. Dynamic link object has no url");
            }
        }];

        if (handled) { 
            return YES; 
        } else {
            // may do other things with incoming URL
            return NO;
        }

    } else { return NO; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *FIRDLDictionaryFromQuery(NSString *queryString) {
    NSArray<NSString *> *keyValuePairs = [queryString componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];

    NSMutableDictionary *queryDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:keyValuePairs.count];

    for (NSString *pair in keyValuePairs) {
        NSArray *keyValuePair = [pair componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
        if (keyValuePair.count == 2) {
            NSString *key = keyValuePair[0];
            NSString *value = [keyValuePair[1] stringByRemovingPercentEncoding];
            [queryDictionary setObject:value forKey:key];
        }
    }
}
```

Then I tracking FIRDynamicLinks and found the root cause.

Dynamic link for iOS with filter char of @"&" and @"=" , according to the `keyValuePair.count == 2`, my params be dropped who the keyword of [link].

Due to my long dynamic link has two [=] symbol before first [&] symbol, keyValuePair.count is 3.

So that my dynamic link object hasn't link parameter and return nil

I think url have to refer to [Manually constructing a Dynamic Link URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually) , and try to be the same.

Finally, I found to similar symptom [Deep Link does not contain valid required params](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61289841/3180224), link value have to percent encoded, solving my confuse and my issue.

But interesting, Android platform without this symptom, the same long dynamic link is workable.