# Firebase dynamic links doesn`t work on first launch unity ios

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

App does not recieve dynamicLinkReceived event after first launch on Ios. When app has been installed everything works correct.

For reference, my code for iOS

```
  FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread( task =>
  {
    var dependencyStatus = task.Result;
    if ( dependencyStatus != DependencyStatus.Available )
    {
      Debug.LogError( "Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: " + dependencyStatus );
      return;
    }              
    DynamicLinks.DynamicLinkReceived += dynamicLinkReceived;       
  });
```

On android everything works correct.

I found a similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70574110/firebase-dynamic-links-on-unity-ios-says-deep-link-does-not-contain-valid-requi), but this does not help me.

I guess something wrong with plist for ios.

```
PBXProject proj = new PBXProject();
string projPath = PBXProject.GetPBXProjectPath(buildPath);
proj.ReadFromFile( projPath );

string mainTarget = proj.GetUnityMainTargetGuid();
string plistPath = buildPath + "/Info.plist";
PlistDocument plist = new PlistDocument();
plist.ReadFromString( File.ReadAllText( plistPath ) );
PlistElementDict rootDict = plist.root;
rootDict.SetBoolean("FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled", false);
var array = rootDict.CreateArray( "FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains" );
array.AddString( "https://referral.myapp.mycompany.com" );
File.WriteAllText( plistPath, plist.WriteToString() );
```

Can somebody suggest how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem, you should add `FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains` string ending with '/' symbol(for links without some prefix)