# Firebase DynamicLinks handleUniversalLink returns always false

Tags: ios, firebase, dynamic, firebase-dynamic-links, dynamic-links

When handling a dynamic link with the **app installed** FIRDynamicLinks handleUniversalLink returns always false and the callback never gets called.

We have a subdomain already linked: https://app.[mycompany].com/ so the `apple-app-site-association` file is ready and reachable.

The FirebaseDynamicLinks SDK is in our app pods (v 4.0.1)
Our app cababilities include as Associated Domains both: `applinks:*.[mycompany].com` and `applinks:app.[mycompany].com`
We are using Xcode 11.3.1 and our AppDelegate is in Objective-C

This is our AppDelegate code following the [documentation from Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=108&v=iSC5ed6OowA&feature=emb_logo) :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void(^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * __nullable restorableObjects))restorationHandler
    {

        // DynamicLinks: App installed. universal link
        NSURL *incomingURL = userActivity.webpageURL;

        if (incomingURL != nil) {
            NSLog(@"incoming URL: %@",incomingURL);
            BOOL linkHandled = [[FIRDynamicLinks dynamicLinks] handleUniversalLink:incomingURL
                                                                        completion:^(FIRDynamicLink * _Nullable dynamicLink, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                if (error != nil) {
                    NSLog(@"error transforming: %@ into a dynamicLink (%@): ", incomingURL, error.localizedDescription);
                } else if (dynamicLink != nil) {
                    [self handleIncomingDynamicLink:dynamicLink];
                }
            }];

            if (linkHandled) {
                return true;
            } else {

                // OLD universal link handling
                NSLog(@"incoming URL not handled");
            }
        }
        return NO;
    }
```

The dynamic link is:
https://app.[mycompany].com/?link=https://[mycompany].com/[featureID]?token%3D12345&isi=[1234567890]&ibi=com.[mycompany].app
And it has been generated directly from the Firebase console following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLBjAg6HvG0&feature=youtu.be).

Still the boolean for the linkHandled is **always false and the callback never gets called**.

We've checked:

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/380
and 
[Firebase dynamic linking - Continueuseractivity not returning dynamic link url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39657454/firebase-dynamic-linking-continueuseractivity-not-returning-dynamic-link-url)

but they were no helpful.

Comment: Are you using a custom domain?
So, do you want to handle link https://app.[mycompany].com via Firebase?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @buddhabath  Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please verify you have Team ID set in Firebase Console - Settings - General - Your apps - [App name] - Team ID